# Check if MongoDB upsert did an insert or an update

Tags: mongodb

I can't find this in the documentation in any of the obvious places.
I'd like to know if it is possible to know if Mongo executed an insert or update in the upsert operation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes there is, on a safe call (or getLastError) the update function will return an array with an upsert field and a updatedExisting field.

You can read the PHP version of this here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php towards the bottom.

As it says within the documentation on `upserted`:

> If an upsert occured, this field will contain the new record's _id field. For upserts, either this field or updatedExisting will be present (unless an error occurred).

So upserted contains the `_id` of the new record if a insert was done or it will increment `updatedExisting`  if it updated a record.

I am sure a similar thing appears in all drivers.

#### Edit

It will actually be a boolean in the `updatedExisting` field of `true` or `false`

Answer (score 11):

For reference only, in node.js:

```
collection.update( source, target, { upsert: true }, function(err, result, upserted) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: That looks like mongoose, right? If so, be careful, if you're using the latest version (3.6) the callback parameters are different now:  (err, numberAffected, rawResponse)

Comment: No, that's mongodb driver direct. However it might have changed since I posted it.

Comment: The names source and target are a little misleading IMO.

Answer (score 10):

For reference only, in node.js using Mongoose 3.6:

```
model.update( findquery, updatequery, { upsert: true }, function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
  ...
});
```

Where rawResponse looks like this when it has updated an existing document:

```
{ updatedExisting: true,
  n: 1,
  connectionId: 222,
  err: null,
  ok: 1 }
```

And it looks like this when it has created a new document:

```
{ updatedExisting: false,
  upserted: 51eebc080eb3e2208a630d8e,
  n: 1,
  connectionId: 222,
  err: null,
```

(Both cases would return numberAffected = 1)

Answer (score 6):

The Answer was taken from "MongoDB Applied Design Patterns" Book
![determine whether an upsert was an insert
or an update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikXsE.png)

Comment: The result is a UpdateResult http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/result/UpdateResult.html

Answer (score 2):

Using MongoDB driver `3.5.9` under Node.js, I found that there are these properties we are interested in after using `updateOne` with `{ upsert: true }`:

```
{
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

When upsert inserted something, we will get `upsertedCount > 0` and `upsertedId` will hold the newly inserted document ID. When upsert modified something, we will get `modifiedCount > 0`.

The tutorial for all CRUD operations is here https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/crud/