# How to determine, if FindOneAndUpdate resulted in Upsert in official C# MongoDB Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How should I know, if resulted `model` was upserted?

```
FilterDefinition<T> filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", modelId);
UpdateDefinition<T> update = ... ;

var opts = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T>()
{
    IsUpsert = true,
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
};

var model = this.Collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, opts);
```

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955212/check-if-mongodb-upsert-did-an-insert-or-an-update

Comment: @dyouberg thank you, but the question was for mongodb c# driver, not the mongodb itself. I could not find any suitable method, that can update/upsert single document, based on UpdateDefinition<T> and returns not just the resulting model, but also an information, whether that model was upserted.